# Generating jar for JavaFX project in Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

While I was playing around with Kotlin I wondered if I can generat a jar for a JavaFX app written in Kotlin. So I wrote a simple app and it worked on IntelliJ IDEA, but when I decided to generate the jar it never worked! It says that it can't find or load the main class.

I guess the problem is that when it asked for the main class in the project settings I entered the application class name (which doesn't contain the main method, as it has to be at the package level) while in pure Java I could just put the main method inside the application class and it would work perfectly. So how should I get around this?

**EDIT:** just tried changing the target from JavaFX Application to a normal Jar and it worked. Don't know why it's not working with the JavaFX Application target.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your main function defined in package named `foo.bar`:

```
package foo.bar

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   // ...
}
```

Then, your main class is `foo.bar.BarPackage` - it is generated by Kotlin compiler to hold top-level functions of the package

Comment: when I tried doing this, it raised an exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in the final executable.

Comment: In current Kotlin, this is no longer how top-level functions are named.  The name of the file containing the function (for example, `App.kt` containing `main()` withing package `foo.bar`) would generate the main within a class called `foo.bar.AppKT` which can be changed use a file level annotation `@file:JvmName("SomeOtherName")`